# Custom Scaffolder Extension Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, scaffolding

I have a custom scaffolding extension for VS2017 that is selectable from the dialog that appears when you select "add new scaffolded item" from the menu that appears when right clicking a project.

Currently, when installed to VS2019, the extension does not appear.

I've attempted to follow the steps in this post: https://madskristensen.net/blog/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/, but this did not fix my issue.

Does anyone have any experience upgrading a scaffolding extension from VS2017 to VS2019 and could point me in the right direction?

Thanks.